# Stop Atom Juno from showing windows automatically

Tags: julia, atom-editor, openstack-juno

I don't know since when Juno in Atom offers the function to show a window automatically wherever you point to. It is very annoying to have windows pop out when I work. Does anyone know how to disable this function? I am not even sure which packgage leads to this function.
[image]